# Find with 3 execs

Tags: bash, find, exec

I wrote this command:

```
find -exec test -e "{}/meta" ";" -exec du -h -t 500M {} ";"
```

It checks if file `meta` is in location and if it's whole location bigger than 500MB. Now I want to read first line of this `meta` file. I tried with this

```
find -exec test -e "{}/meta" ";" -exec test du -h -t 500M {} ";" -exec sed '1q;d' {}/meta ";"
```

or this

```
find -exec test -e "{}/meta" ";" -exec du -h -t 500M {} ";" -exec head -n 1 {}/meta ";"
```

But it ignores `du` and read line from every `meta` file.
How it should looks like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a try with `find . -type d -size +500M`, it appears that the `-size` option applied to directory does not check its total file size.

Searching for the desired file and checking its directory size should be the better approach:

```
find . -type f -name 'meta' -execdir bash -c 's=$(du -sh .); [[ "${s%M*}" -gt "500" ]] && sed "1q" meta' \;
```

Comment: Or simply `sed "1q"` which will exit early.

Comment: @DzikiChrzan Updated with `-execdir` and `{}/meta` to restrict commands in found directory.

Comment: @DzikiChrzan Are you sure that this works? I think the `-size` option of `find` does not return something meaningful on directories.

Comment: @DzikiChrzan You'd better check the update. Tell me if it works.

Comment: You're right @gniourf_gniourf. I removed this line as it was not a much reliable command.

Answer (score 1):

I would actually use a `while` loop in bash for this, like that:

```
find -type d | \
    while IFS= read -r dir; do
        if (($(du -ms -- "$dir" | cut -f1) >= 500)); then
            [[ -e "$dir/meta" ]] && head -n1 "$dir/meta"
        fi
    done
```

I am also not relying on the `-t` flag of `du` because it only affects the output, not the status code of `du, so I just use a simple arithmetic comparison in bash instead.

Comment: I don't want check `meta` file for size, but directory in which `meta` is located.

Comment: @DzikiChrzan So you need the first line from all `meta`'s residing in a directory with at least 500 MB of size?

Comment: Exactly, that's why I used `test -e "{}/meta"` - check for existence of meta file.

Comment: @DzikiChrzan I rewrote my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach would be to use -execdir:

```
find -name meta -type f -execdir bash -c 's=($(du -s .)) ; (( s > 2000 ))'  \; -exec head -n1 {} \;
```